# How to export a table as a geometry in Google Earth Engine Code Editor

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, geometry, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have imported my shapefile into GEE which is in my assets folder as a table. I extracted the shape from the table using this code:

```js
table = table.geometry();
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table, {color: 'red'}, 'table');
```

This allows the shape to be visible but remains a layer and not geometry. I want to be able to have the shapefile in my assets readily available to import as geometry as the code I need to run requires the shape to be a geometry.

[image: GEE]

Comment: Did you try to call your `table` in the code where you need it? What type of error did you get when you tried it? Because your code demonstrates that your `table` has a `.geometry`, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Table is a conventional name assigned for GEE code editor when you import "shapefile" from your assets and you can change it for another one. It is a FeatureCollection that already has a geometry. You can use it directly for bounding or clipping an Image or a ImageCollection.

Answer (score 3):

Shapefiles in GEE are registered as tables, if you want it to be a geometry just add the following (I named it studyArea but you can keep the name table if that suits you):

```
var studyArea = ee.FeatureCollection(table).geometry()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted my EVI layers to be exported as .gif but the console said it cannot compute for my geometry which is a table (shapefile) like yours.

- First, I tried adding `table = table.geometry();`
- then also added `var studyArea = ee.FeatureCollection(xxxx).geometry()`

Finally the table shape is coverted to geometry and all the gif parameters works

Comment: In what way this answer differs from the other one?